# Trying to send attachments with PHP mail()

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to store an uploaded file from a form to the uploads folder as well as send the file as an attachment to an email. The email sends perfectly fine and there is also an attachment, however the attachment is unreadable/corrupted.

I have tried with multiple file types and that makes no difference, I still have the same errors.

```
    <?php

//Store File
if (!empty($_FILES) && isset($_FILES['upload'])) {
    switch ($_FILES['upload']["error"]) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            $target = "uploads/";
            $target = $target . basename($_FILES['upload']['name']);

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
                $status        = "The file " . basename($_FILES['upload']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
                $imageFileType = pathinfo($target, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            } else {
                $status = "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
            }
            break;

    }

    echo "Status: {$status}<br/>\r\n";

}


$fileatt      = getcwd() . "/uploads"; // Path to the file
$fileatt_type = "application/pdf"; // File Type
$fileatt_name = $_FILES['upload']['name']; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment

$email_from    = $_POST['email']; // Who the email is from
$email_subject = "Your attached file"; // The Subject of the email
$email_message = "Thanks for visiting mysite.com! Here is your free file.";
$email_message .= "Thanks for visiting."; // Message that the email has in it

$email_to = 'test@test.com'; // Who the email is to

$headers = "From: " . $email_from;

$file = fopen($fileatt . "/" . $fileatt_name, 'rb');
$data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt . "/" . $fileatt_name));
fclose($file);

$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n" . "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n" . $email_message .= $_POST['email'] . "<br>" . $_POST['firstname'] . "<br>" . $_POST['surname'] . "<br>" . $_POST['degree'] . "<br>" . "\r\n\r\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n" . "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\r\n" . " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\r\n" . "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n" . " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\r\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n" . $data .= "\r\n\r\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}--\r\n";

$ok = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

if ($ok) {
    echo "You file has been sent
    to the email address you specified.

    Make sure to check your junk mail!

    Click here to return to mysite.com.";

} else {
    die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!");
}


?>
```

Please could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would recommend using some mail library, like PHPMailer, Swift Mailer or similar instead. It makes these kind of things much easier.

Comment: Maybe the newline between `content-type: multipart/mixed` and `boundary...` shouldn't be here. That's a quick guess by having a glance at your code and comparing it to my own email lib. Maybe you should dump here your `$email_message` and `$headers`. Choose a very tiny attachment (several bytes) so that it will be short enough to fit here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send attachments with PHP Mail()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail)

Answer (score -2):

You can find the solution here.

Explained completely to need to ass same info again.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail)